# Text with a background image with FOP

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using FOP api with XSL to generate the PDF.

My requirement is to write some text on top of a background image. Any possible way suggested will be helpful.

Comment: You should provide more details like is the background full page size or just something smaller. Is the position fixed or does it flow?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`background-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#background-image) property:

```
<fo:block background-image="image.png">Lorem ipsum.</fo:block>
```

You can control repetition and position of the image using [`background-repeat`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#background-repeat), [`background-position-horizontal`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#background-position-horizontal) and [`background-position-vertical`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#background-position-vertical):

```
<fo:block background-image="image.png" background-repeat="no-repeat">Lorem ipsum.</fo:block>

<fo:block background-image="image.png" background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position-horizontal="center">Lorem ipsum.</fo:block>
```

Comment: If the answer was useful, consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as a useful hint for future users with a similar problem; if it wasn't useful, you could try [adding some more details to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) to attract better answers.

Comment: this did not help as for <fo:block> the attribute "background-image" is not available. Do i need to use the recent jar? It is just an assumption..not sure about it...

Comment: @user2498307 Which version of FOP are you using? Do you get a warning / error message? I tried with trunk, 1.1 and even 0.20.5, and `background-image` was correctly implemented.

Comment: @lfurini:- have tried background-image in block.. but its showing `Image Not Found`

Comment: I used your suggestion in "fo:region-body" tag in order to generate watermark effect. It works perfect. Many thx.